# How to present a view of an Item with multiple Parts without duplicating the item name?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

This is my dataset right now:

```
List <Orders> myOrders;

itemName    itemQuantity    partName    unitQuantity    totalQuantity
A           2               X           0.5             1
A           2               Y           2               4
A           2               Z           7               14
```

To summarize:

- there is an order of 2 (itemQuantity) of an Item called A (itemName)
- this item has 3 parts: X,Y,Z (partNames) with their own quantities (and this is why for each item A there will be 3 rows, one for each of the parts for that item)
- totalQuantity is unitQuantity*itemQuantity (how many parts of type X do we need for 2 item A's for example)

All the data is there, but this is confusing to the customer as they see 3 rows of "item A", instead I need to show the customer (visualy on screen using WPF) the following:

```
itemName    itemQuantity    partName    unitQuantity    totalQuantity
A           2               X           0.5             1
                            Y           2               4
                            Z           7               14
```

Notice the data has not changed but now we do not repeat the itemName or itemQuantity for each part and it looks like the list of parts belong to that one itemName (A). Essentually it is visually clearer and thus less confusing (as it seems all grouped up) from the person reading it.

Same data, differnet FORMAT, and I am unable to find out how I can "transform" my data OR do some magic in my XAML (WPF) to make it look this way to the customer on the screen. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Many gridview implementations have a grouping feature which allows one to visually group rows in the data source. How are you presenting this? If I am not mistaken, the `ListView` control in WPF does support grouping.

Comment: I am looking to present it in anyway that works, I am using WPF and the page is empty so I have free choice to select anything I want as long as it comes out looking like my example above (or something equally clear).

Comment: Well, in that case I recommend that you take a look at the grouping feature of `ListView` and see if you like the result.

Answer (score 1):

what type of target control you aims to binding ? Instead of trying XAML, you simplify to write a custom class to achieve to sort it out. Simply, Pass your IList in the custom class and eliminate the repeated value to empty value and bind to the target control.

Comment: Target Control? Honestly I have an empty WPF page and I can use anything I want. I just want it to look like my example (or something equivalently clear).

As for the "custom class" and "empty values", honestly I had not even thought about it (what a great idea!). I would still rather use something less hacky but if nothing else comes up that is for sure a great solution (thanks).

Comment: If you feel this is help you after come up conclusion. just mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have gotten various answers [on using TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423802/200449) and [other variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429302/datagrid-within-a-datagrid-having-one-of-the-columns-of-a-datagrid-as-a-datagri)

I believe you might be interested to consider Master-Detail DataBinding:

- [24.129.21.Master Detail Binding](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/MasterDetailBinding.htm)
- [24.130.1.Bind to a Collection with the Master-Detail Pattern](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/BindtoaCollectionwiththeMasterDetailPattern.htm)

Here are screenshots from the first reference:

[image: Addams company chosen]

Fig.1. The Addams company chosen

[image: Stooge Company chosen]

Fig.2. The Stoge company chosen

Or if to remove one of the companies:

[image]