# How to display a collection inside a collection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following classes:

```
public class Order
{
public string OrderName { get; set; }
public List<Parts> PartsList { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
public string PartName { get; set; }
public double PartQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I create a list of `Order` objects

```
List<Order> myOrders;
```

I would like to display all of this to the user somehow, like using a stack panel of elements where the first is a TextBox to display `OrderName` and the second is a `Datagrid` to display the list of Parts?

Honestly I am trying many different things (I have no requirements on what type of controls to use) but I can never get the `PartsList` to show correctly (either I get nothing OR I get "`Collection`" show to the user.

The goal would be to see something like this:

```
Order1    Part1    7
          Part2    12
Order2    Part1    100
          Part2    1
          Part3    58
```

Or whatever, headers can be whatever, honestly I am open to many suggestions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using fields instead of properties? I know for sure WinForms data binding needs properties, and I would not be surprised if the same is true for WPF.

Comment: Added properties to each, didn't make a difference in being able to display them to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a `TreeView` work? It would look something like this:

```
- Order 1
  * Part A (100)
  * Part B (200)
+ Order 2
+ Order 3
- Order 4
  * Part C (300)
  * Part D (400)
  * Part E (500)
+ Order 5
...
```

You could do something like this:

```
void AddOrderToTree(Order order)
{
  var orderNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(order);

  foreach(var part in order.Parts)
    orderNode.Nodes.Add(part);
}
```

But yes, as pointed out, I would use properties like so:

```
public class Part
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual double Quantity { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("{0}: {1}", this.Name, this.Quantity.ToString());
  }
}

public class Order
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Part> Parts { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  { 
    return this.Name;
  }
}
```

Comment: The use of properties wasn't the 'problem' with your code, but it's a good practice compared to publicly accessible fields. My recommendation was to use a `TreeView` control to display the data. By overriding the `ToString()` method on the classes, you can control how it will display in the `TreeViewNode` objects.